# jQuery - .each() returning only the first element attributes, need to store each element attribute and use in each child element

Tags: jquery, attributes, element, for-loop, each

I'm having headaches trying to make this work: I have a <a> element with a background-image defined with *style=""* attribute and I have put a function to append inside the <a> element a <span> handling different background-positions for :hover effects with opacity changes. The thing is, I need to get the same style attribute from **each** <a> element to **each** child <span> but only the first background-image is copied to all the <span> elements, even using *$("span.hover").parent().attr("style")* as selector!

http://pastebin.me/ac4cc52af64f6e831366ca61c7bbe63b

Above you can see how it looks like and see that it's *not* working properly.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much Greg! I've spent the whole night to figure this out and I was about to give up! Thanks!

Comment: I've optmized the script and removed a few lines, now it's working fast and IE8 is rendering the correctly - http://pastebin.me/c421b31f354f6630dd71cc5dff95665d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
var $ans = $("span.hover").parent().attr("style");
```

should be

```
var $ans = $(this).parent().attr("style");
```

You're re-getting all the spans each time, which gives you the first one.

Tested & working.

Comment: This is one of the most common mistakes people make with `each`.